# Python importing pam module error

Tags: python, authentication, import, module, pam

I'm building a web app in Python with Django and I want the users to authenticate with pam, in order to use their system credentials.

I'm developing on Windows now, so I installed pam module through pip with

```
pip install python-pam
```

and it worked perfectly

```
Collecting python-pam
Downloading python-pam-1.8.2.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: python-pam
Running setup.py install for python-pam ... done
Successfully installed python-pam-1.8.2
```

But then, when I try to import it in Python env with a simple import I get this error:

```
>>> import pam
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\pam.py", line 70, in <module>
        libc                      = CDLL(find_library("c"))
    File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 348, in  __init__
        self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
TypeError: LoadLibrary() argument 1 must be str, not None
>>>
```

Am I missing something during installation or what?

Thanks everybody in advance guys.

### UPDATE #1

Ok, the problem slightly move on: i skipped using python_pam directly when found django_pan, so i installed it from my virtual environment (everything ok), and following [this guide](http://django-pam.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) i've been able to call the default login page.

The problem now arise when i try to log in using the default form: after have inserted my credential and clicked the login button i got the django debug error page, the one woth the yellow header, the stack trace, etc..

The problem is still the same:

```
  File "c:\program files\python36\Lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 348, in __init__
self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
TypeError: LoadLibrary() argument 1 must be str, not None
```

I tried upgrading django_pam with pip3 but nothing new:

```
(django_test) X:\RnD\smanetti\Python\Django\django_test\mysite>pip3 install django-pam
Requirement already satisfied: django-pam in x:\rnd\smanetti\python\django\django_test\lib\site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: python-pam in x:\rnd\smanetti\python\django\django_test\lib\site-packages (from django-pam)
Requirement already satisfied: six in x:\rnd\smanetti\python\django\django_test\lib\site-packages (from django-pam)

(django_test) X:\RnD\smanetti\Python\Django\django_test\mysite>pip3 install django-pam --upgrade
Requirement already up-to-date: django-pam in x:\rnd\smanetti\python\django\django_test\lib\site-packages
Requirement already up-to-date: six in x:\rnd\smanetti\python\django\django_test\lib\site-packages (from django-pam)
Requirement already up-to-date: python-pam in x:\rnd\smanetti\python\django\django_test\lib\site-packages (from django-pam)
```

googling around got me no clues...

Comment: Try this: pip3 install python-pam

Comment: Looks like a version compatibility issue. Use virtualenv to properly install and then use it

Comment: tried pip3 in virtualenv, both install and upgrade, still got the error, check update #1.

Comment: I am also facing same issue. Have you got any solution for this?